# Integer divisors of an integer

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Determine all positive integers $N$ to which the following applies (i) $N$ has more than three different positive integer divisors 
and (ii) for all divisors $p,q$ of $N$ with $1 < p < q < N$, also $q-p$ is a divisor of $N$.

$N$ will have 2 as a divisor. Because if $N$ only had odd divisors the difference q-p would be even and it cannot divide $N$ as $N$ only has odd divisors. Contradiction - 2 must be a divisor.

Comment: Any thoughts?  Can you, say, exhibit a few numbers that work?  Maybe spot a simple pattern?

Comment: Ruling out 1 and N itself I ran through some factor combinations and got e.g.30, 36, 48, 120 that worked out. What makes even more difficult for me is that the factors themselves can be composite.

Comment: $30$ works?  But $2,15$ divide $30$ and $13=15-2$ does not.

Comment: Similarly, $2,18$ divide $36$ but $16$ does not.  I'll let you confirm that your other numbers are wrong as well.

Comment: n=10000;
Select[Select[Range[n],Length[Divisors[#]]>=4&],Complement[Map[#[[2]]-#[[1]]&,Subsets[Complement[Divisors[#],{1,#}],{2}]],Divisors[#]]=={}&]

in Mathematica yields

{6,8,12}

so these should be the only ones. Will think about why.

Comment: How stupid of me - now looking at Mario´s examples e.g. 6 with divisors (1), 2 , 3 , (6) and (3-2) = 1 or

Comment: You can show that $2$ must be a divisor; then that its prime factorisation cannot have two odd primes in it (not even the same odd prime twice); then that the only odd prime it can have as a factor is $3$; and finally determine what power of $2$ is possible.

Comment: @Jaap Scherphuis: Thank you. You have a very rigorous answer it seems, but could you give some more hints or explanations? I would appreciate your help very much (just starting with number theory

Comment: Suppose $N$ only has odd divisors. What will happen then?

Comment: The difference q-p will be even and it cannot divide N as N only has odd divisors ... So 2 must be a divisor.

Comment: Correct. Note also that we are given that $N$ has at least 4 divisors, so excluding $1$ and $N$ leaves at least two divisors p,q to which property (ii) can be applied. So 2 is a divisor. For the next step you can do something slightly better than what I wrote previously. Suppose q is the largest odd divisor, and take p=2. Where does that lead?

Comment: That will give another odd divisor < q, But what would be the consequence? You stated that there cannot be two odd primes ... here I lost you.

Comment: Suppose q>1 is the largest odd divisor of N. We know 2 is a divisor of N and by rule (ii) we get that q and q-2 are both odd divisors. So what about q*(q-2)? Since q and q-2 are coprime, q(q-2) must also be an odd divisor of N. But this cannot be larger than q, so q-2=1. Hence the largest odd divisor of N is 3 (or 1).

Comment: @Jaap Scherphuis - Very much appreciate your explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that

(i) $n$ has at least four different divisors (i.e at least two different divisors apart from $1$ and $n$)

(ii) for all divisors $p,q$ of $n$ with $1<p<q<n$, $q-p$ is also a divisor of $n$.

Claim 1: $2$ divides $n$.

Assume to the contrary that $2$ does not divide $n$. Let $p,q$ be divisors of $n$ such that $1<p<q<n$ (they exist by (i)). Then $p$ and $q$ are odd, so $q-p$ is even and a divisor of $n$ by (ii), so $n$ is even which is a contradiction. Thus $2$ divides $n$.

Claim 2: If $n$ is not a power of $2$, then $3$ divides $n$.

Assume to the contrary that $3$ does not divide $n$. Let $p$ be a prime divisor of $n$. Then $p\geq5$. By (ii) and induction, $p-2k$ is a divisor of $n$ for all $k\in\{1,\ldots,(p-1)/2\}$ ($p$ and $2$ are divisors, so $p-2$ is, so $p-4$ is, so $\ldots$). So $p-2((p-1)/2-1)=3$ is a divisor of $n$ which is a contradictions. This $3$ divides $n$.

Claim 3: $n$ cannot have any prime divisors apart from $2$ and $3$.

Assume to the contrary that $n$ has a prime divisor that is not $2$ or $3$. Let $p_1,\ldots,p_\ell$ be all distinct prime divisors of $n$ that are not $2$ or $3$. Then $p:=2p_1\cdots p_\ell$ is a divisor of $n$ and so is $2p-3$ by (ii). Neither $2$, nor $3$, nor any of the $p_i$ divides $2p-3$, so $2p-3$ has a prime divisor that is not in the set $\{2,3,p_1,\ldots,p_\ell\}$ which is a contradiction. Thus $n$ cannot have any prime divisors apart from $2$ and $3$.

So now you know that $n$ is of the form $2^u3^v$. I'll leave it to you to show that $6,8,12$ are the only options.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comprehensive and well written explanation. Yet I will need some time to work through your solution.